# group by count in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables employee and office. 
employe table contains columns (emp_id,office_id,firstname,lastname,startdate)
office table contaisn columns (office_id,office_name,country)

I would like to query for:
All the countries that have offices, and the number of employees in that country

Comment: This was already asked and answered many times, use the search function or look at the list in the "Related" column on the right.

Comment: @Jocelyn i checked but was unable to draw the sollution

Comment: possible duplicate of [Count and group non-empty values in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334978/count-and-group-non-empty-values-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you the number of employees by country.

```
SELECT o.country,
       COUNT(*)
  FROM office o
    INNER JOIN employee e ON e.office_id = o.office_id
  GROUP BY o.country
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(e.emp_id), o.county 
FROM office AS o 
INNER JOIN employee AS e 
ON e.office_id = o.office_id;
```

You'll probably have to tweet that a bit, but it's a starting point.

Comment: mysql> select * from employee;

+-------------+-----------+------------+-----------+------------+
|           1 |        60 | john       | back      | 2013-12-02 |
|           2 |        69 | sam        | mac       | 2010-11-02 |
|           3 |        60 | tim        | jack      | 2010-01-03 |
|           4 |        69 | timy       | jack      | 2010-12-03 |
|           5 |        69 | emma       | pec       | 2010-12-02 |
|           6 |        90 | emmand     | pecy      | 2009-11-02 |

Comment: mysql> select count(e.employee_id),o.country from office o INNER JOIN employee e on e.office_id = o.office_id;
+----------------------+---------+
| count(e.employee_id) | country |
+----------------------+---------+
|                    6 | UK      |

Comment: I don't have a database in front of me, hence I said it's a starting point. The query will be SIMILAR to this, not that this query IS THE SOLUTION.