# MySQL if statements (with method invocations)?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How do I do the following pseudocode in MySQL:

```
if (a IS NOT NULL)
{
    GROUP BY (id)
    num = COUNT(*)
} else {
    num = 0
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you want to do?  Your pseudo-code does not make sense, at least to me.

Comment: @GordonLinoff If a isn't null, you `GROUP` and then set num equal to something. Otherwise, it's 0.

Comment: . . Grouping by something typically returns multiple rows, so `num` would not get one value.  Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff no you `GROUP` and then num will be the result from `COUNT()`

Comment: @User3187877 Gordon wrote 'provide sample data and desired results'. You can ignore such helpful hints of course, but your question is already receiving 'close votes'.

Comment: ...and here's the deciding fifth close vote. It's not clear enough what you're trying to accomplish. The pseudocode is open to interpretation. It may be useful as supplemental information, but you need to describe what you're trying to do and illustrate it with an example. You might find this helpful: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Note sure what you are trying to do .....

if you want to count non-null value, check [those examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334978/count-and-group-non-empty-values-in-mysql), it would look like this

```
COUNT(NULLIF(a, ''))
```

Also consider use [Case](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html) if you need more complete counting

```
CASE
        WHEN a = 'something' COUNT(1)
        ELSE NULL
```

**EDIT**

If you want to invoke some query, depend on some value, consider use store procedure/ function

Comment: I need to invoke a method not just a value.

Comment: @Mzf . . . Your code does not match your description.

Comment: @user3187877 Then learn procedure/function  in MySQL.

Comment: `consider use store procedure` Why not function for single value.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan I'm not sure what he/she want to do. Function are fine also, I update the answer

Comment: @Mzf yes question is unclear. But it seem method doesn't affect the state of database and OP wants to return a value so function is correct choice.

Answer (score 0):

This may be the code you are looking for:

```
select num := count(distinct id)
from t;
```

This will set `num` to `0` if there are no rows.

If you really want the comparison to `NULL`:

```
select num := (case when a is not null then count(distinct id) else 0 end)
from t;
```

Note this assumes that `a` and `num` are *not* columns in the database.